# Set authentification/authorization page in specific language

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

In my Forge-based web application, I need the user to log in to his Autodesk account, then to authorize the application to access/write in BIM 360 Team (3-legged authentification).

The first time he logs in, these pages are displayed in English. If he logs out then logs in again, they are in French (because the account belongs to a French user ?).

How could I always show them in French, even at the beginning ?
I am using the following endpoint :

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/forge/oauth/url")]
    public string GetOAuthURL()
    {
        ThreeLeggedApi _threeLeggedApi = new ThreeLeggedApi();

        string oauthUrl = _threeLeggedApi.Authorize(
            Credentials.GetAppSetting("FORGE_CLIENT_ID"),
            oAuthConstants.CODE,
            Credentials.GetAppSetting("FORGE_CALLBACK_URL"),
            new Scope[] { Scope.DataRead, Scope.DataCreate, Scope.DataWrite, Scope.ViewablesRead, Scope.BucketRead, Scope.BucketCreate });

        return oauthUrl;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the signin page has no information of the user (e.g. cookie from previous session), it will assume the browser language preference. Sorry we don't have option to customize it.

Comment: My brower language preference is set to French, but it redirects me to the English log in page... A pity we don't have option to set this.